# add data from html forms to database. undefined sql error and empty query error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add data from html form to database. However , I think everthing is OK but there are 2 errors: undefined sql and empty query. I research something and I learned sql injection but I dont understand what is the difference in INSERT INTO query. How can I solve this problem?(I have also one more column in database its name is id and it is auto inceremented. So I havent add it)

```
<?php 
include('dbConnection.php'); 
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addMember.css">
    <script src="addMember.js"></script>
    <title>Nature Apartment-Add Member</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nature Apartment</h1>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$apartmentID= $_REQUEST['apartmentID'];
 $uname= $_REQUEST['uname'];
 $pwd= $_REQUEST['pwd'];
 $phoneNumber= $_REQUEST['phoneNumber'];
 $secondPhoneNumber= $_REQUEST['secondPhoneNumber'];
 $whoseNumber= $_REQUEST['whoseNumber'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (apartmentID, username, password, phoneNumber, secondPhoneNumber, whoseNumber)
VALUES '$apartmentID', '$uname', '$pwd', '$phoneNumber', '$secondPhoneNumber', '$whoseNumber')";
    }
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="AdminHomePage.html">HomePage</a></li>
        <li><a href="AdminMembers.html">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="AdminPayments.html">Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="AdminGeneralExpenses.html">General Expenses</a> </li>
        <li><a href="Chat.html">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="AdminSettings.html">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br><br>
        <h2>Add New Member</h2>
        <br><br>
        <form id="form" method="POST" >
            <label for="apartmentID">Apartment ID</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="id" name="id"><br><br>
            <label for="username">Username</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname"><br><br>
            <label for="Password">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"><br><br>
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"><br><br>
            <label for="secondPhoneNumber">Second phone number</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="secondPhoneNumber" name="secondPhoneNumber"><br><br>
            <label for="whoseNumber">Whose phone number? </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="whoseNumber" name="whoseNumber"><br><br>
            <input  type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" >
          </form>
       



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @tadman Here is the link for the php: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp It's still standard to use those $db = new mysqli(…) and $db->prepare("…") contary to your agruement, and its W3C the accepted standard, not sure where you got that it was obsolete??

Comment: @YunfeiChen A) w3schools has absolutely nothing to do with W3C, as does PHP. B) I'm advocating *for* the use of `new` and `$db->...`, not the opposite.

Comment: @tadman Really it sounded like "obsolete mysql_query interface where missing a single i can cause trouble. Example: $db = new mysqli(…) and $db->prepare("…")" You were saying that "$db = new mysqli(…) and $db->prepare("…")" is a "obsolete mysql_query interface"???

Comment: @YunfeiChen If it's confusing I'll work on rephrasing that. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @tadman Also "A) w3schools has absolutely nothing to do with W3C, as does PHP." Really I thought w3schools was the site that W3C build to educate people about web development, because when I search W3C, W3schools shows up in the results??

Comment: @tadman Also this guy's lack of code indention is driving me crazy....

Comment: @YunfeiChen W3C has **absolutely nothing** to do with w3schools. The name was chosen by the company running the site to confuse itself with the actual W3C group. It's a blight on the industry and has done irreparable harm to developers for years now. Even linking to it is harmful. It's basically the "WikiHow" for programming, chock full of bad advice and out-dated material.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a bracket??

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (apartmentID, username, password, phoneNumber, secondPhoneNumber, whoseNumber)
VALUES '$apartmentID', '$uname', '$pwd', '$phoneNumber', '$secondPhoneNumber', '$whoseNumber')";
```

Should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (apartmentID, username, password, phoneNumber, secondPhoneNumber, whoseNumber)
VALUES **(**'$apartmentID', '$uname', '$pwd', '$phoneNumber', '$secondPhoneNumber', '$whoseNumber')";
```

Comment: Adding syntax like that within the code for emphasis doesn't help. It might be better to just say `VALUES (...)` not `VALUES ...)`

Comment: Please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry it is important but that is not the issue being discussed here...... He missed a ( making it prepared doesn't fix the fact fact that he had incorrect syntax.....